# The custom visualforce button is not working

Tags: visualforce, community

I had created a custom visualforce button as shown below. That would pre populate the look up field.

```
   <apex:commandLink  value="Create New Order" onclick="/a15/e?CF00N50000003qoqXEAU_lkid='{!Account.Id}'&CF00N50000003qoqXEAU='{!‌​Account.Name}'"/> -->
  <form action="{!URLFOR('/a15/e?' + 'retURL=%2Fa15%2Fo&CF00N50000003qoqX={!Account.Name}&CF00N50000003qoqX_lkid={!Account.Id}')}" target="_blank" >
       <input type="submit" value="Create New Order"/> 
      </form> 
      </div>
      <br/>
```

After clicking the button the output displays as follows [image]

I want the URL to display as

> a15/e?retURL=%2Fa15%2Fo&CF00N50000003qoqX={!Account.Name}&CF00N50000003qoqX_lkid={!Account.Id}

Comment: You have to do something like this:

'retURL=%2Fa15%2Fo&CF00N50000003qoqX='+{!Account.Name}+'&CF00N50000003qoqX_lkid='+{!Account.Id}+'')}'

Comment: Also, its much better to redirect from the backend not the front end. Cause I have feeling that the Account.ID or name is not gonna be set when the page is loaded.
So its better to use an action function and call a submit function in the back end.

Answer (score 2):

Straight after `{!` you are in a server-side evaluated expression so there is no need to use further `{!` expression delimiters. Instead just concatenate the values.

So instead of:

```
{!URLFOR('/a15/e?' + 'retURL=%2Fa15%2Fo&CF00N50000003qoqX={!Account.Name}&CF00N50000003qoqX_lkid={!Account.Id}')}
```

use:

```
{!URLFOR('/a15/e?' + 'retURL=%2Fa15%2Fo&CF00N50000003qoqX=' + Account.Name + '&CF00N50000003qoqX_lkid=' + Account.Id)}
```

Comment: Even after doing that it is showing the page and not prepopulating the look up fields ... the output is as " /a15/e?"

Comment: @DominicSeb When using URLFOR I've passed parameters using his syntax `{! URLFOR($Page.Form, null, [p1='abc', p2='xyz']) }`; the issue might be escaping related.

Comment: I tried using this as follows {!URLFOR($Action.Product_and_Services__c.New,null,['CF00N50000003qoqXEAU_lkid'='Account.Id' , 'CF00N50000003qoqXEAU'='Account.Name'] )}" target="_blank"  It is still blank The look up fields are not getting pre populated

Comment: @DominicSeb I would expect `[CF00N50000003qoqXEAU_lkid = A‌​ccount.Id, CF00N50000003qoqXEAU = Account.Name]` to work.

Comment: I did the following <form action="{!URLFOR($Action.Product_and_Services__c.New,null,[CF00N50000003qoqXEAU_lkid=A‌​ccount.Id ,CF00N50000003qoqXEAU=Account.Name] )}" target="_blank" >  I got the error " Syntax error"

Comment: Never mind I got it working  <apex:commandLink  value="Create New Order" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Product_and_Services__c.CreateNewOrder, Id)}" target="_blank" styleClass="btn linkAsBtn" />